# Relative positioning different in multiple browsers

Tags: css

I have two elements that I am trying to line up, a text box and a span. In order for them to line up and look nice in firefox I use:

```
<input id="myTextBox" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px; position: relative; left: 13.5em; bottom: 1.5em;" type="text" />
<span style="visibility: visible; position: relative; left: 12.5em; bottom: 1.5em;">Enter stuff in the box </span>
```

However in IE 8 the text box is on top of the span, cutting off the text. If I change the left: 13.5em; to left: 11.8em; it lines up nice in Internet Explorer, but then is off center in Firefox. I am using decorators in a Zend Form so I have to use the inline styles. Is there any way to make the position line up in both browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `<input>` is floating, it might make more sense to use `margin-left:10%` instead of `position:relative` and `left:10%`? Similarly for your span, I would make it `display:block;margin-left:10%;clear:left;` rather than `position:relative;`.

I've used `10%` because using `em` for layout has given me cross-browser issues in the past - I only use it for text-based things now.

Comment: Without the position:relative the elements appear lower than they should because the bottom: 1.5em doesn't happen. Using percentages with the position relative FF needs 30.5% and IE needs 26%, so there is still inconsistancies

Comment: You can just use negative margins:- margin-top:-1.5em to do the equivalent to bottom:1.5em :)

Comment: To help with lining things up I'd need to see your issue in context - I need to see how and why the other elements are where they are.

Comment: To be completely honest it is a bit of a mess. I am pretty sure your route is the correct way to go. As a temporary solution I used PHP to conditionally create the elements $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent)) ... but I am going to clean up the form and try to work towards removing position relative.